# How to use reduce with if condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has certain values and I am doing some calculation with it.

Here is my array check out the result:

```js
var arr2 = [1,2,2,3]

var newArr = [["a",0,1,2,0,223],["b",1,0,0,0,0],["c",0,0,0,0,223],["d",0,1,2,0,223]]

const result = newArr.reduce((results, element, index) => {
  return [
    ...results, // push the rest of the results onto the new array
    [
      ...element, // keep all the current items of the element (the 1d array)
      Math.round(element[element.length-1]-(element[element.length-1]/(element[element.length-3]+element[element.length-4])*arr2[index])) // add new element, by querying the last element of the array and the appropriate index of the second array
    ]
  ]
},[]);

console.log(result)
```

It works fine until my divisor becomes 0. In the above code `(element[element.length-3]+element[element.length-4])` sometime results 0 which gives NaN or infinity in array which I don't want instead it can throw zero.

Is there a way that I can use if condition inside it? Or any other solution?

Comment: Do your calculation before return statement and pass the calculated value in array.

Comment: it happen because divide 0 value, you need add condition for check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the 0 value as false; when that happens you can set the divisor as 1.

((element[element.length-3]+element[element.length-4]) || 1)

The other option is to do the calculation in a separate variable.

Comment: Thanks that's was helpful. But could you please explain what is this function called (x || 1).

Comment: I hope I understood correctly your question.That is a logical OR, when the first part is 0 it evaluated to false and returns the 1.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr2 = [1,2,2,3]

var newArr = [["a",0,1,2,0,223],["b",1,0,0,0,0],["c",0,0,0,0,223],["d",0,1,2,0,223]]

const result = newArr.reduce((results, element, index) => {
  const aValue = element[element.length-1]
  const bValue = element[element.length-3] + element[element.length-4]
  const value = aValue != 0 && bValue != 0 ? aValue/bValue : 0
  return [
    ...results, // push the rest of the results onto the new array
    [
      ...element, // keep all the current items of the element (the 1d array)
      Math.round(element[element.length-1]-(value*arr2[index]))
    ]
  ]
},[]);

console.log(result)
```